# Ubuntu Budgie system requirements?

Tags: ubuntu-budgie

I haven't found a documentation for it. I love the look of it but I'm afraid 2GB or ram wouldn't be enough!

Comment: I haven't tested it but if I were to guess I would say somewhere between Xubuntu and Lubuntu. More is better but 2GB of RAM shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I already posted an Ubuntu Budgie answer there on  Nov 9 '16 .